# beamer background repeated figure

Tags: beamer, backgrounds, includegraphics

According to the [beamer documentation](https://latex-beamer.com/faq/background-image-in-latex-beamer/), it is possible to use an image as a background for all slides.

```
\setbeamertemplate{background} 
{
    \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{MyBackground.jpg}
}
```

The code inside `\setbeamertemplate{background}` should create an image of size `\paperwidth`x`\paperheight`.

If I have an image which is smaller than that, and I do not want to resize it, is is possible to have it repeated all over the page, eventually cropping if the size of the image is not congruent to the page size?

Comment: Please always provide complete, compilable code, not just snippets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{multido}

\setbeamertemplate{background}{%
  \parbox{\paperwidth}{\offinterlineskip%
    \multido{}{20}{\multido{}{20}{\includegraphics[width=0.05\paperwidth]{example-image.png}}\newline}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test}
Hello
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```